# Stored Procedure for Employee Clock table

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have an `Employee Clock` table with these columns:

```
EmpID         nvarchar(200)    (FK)
EmpName       nvarchar(100)
Password      nvarchar(100)
punchTime     datetime
punchType     bit
```

I am going to design an application (in C#) that lets employees check in and check out.

The process will be: when an employee wants to check in, they will input their `EmpID` and `Password`, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the backend, the app will run a stored procedure that enters the values of `EmpID, Password, EmpName` (will be retrieved from `Employee` table based on `EmpID`), `punchTime` and `punchType` (= 1 for Check In, 0 for Check Out).

The process of checking out is exactly same as checking in, the employee will just need to enter their `EmpID` and `Password`, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I am looking for a stored procedure that could do something like:

when `keyEnter.hit` (from C#) => run the stored procedure:

- if `max(EmpID)` has `punch = 1` (the employee already checked in), then set `punch = 0` with provided `punchTime` and `EmpID`
- else if `max(EmpID)` has `punch = 0` (the employee already checked out), then set `punch = 1` with `punchTime` and `EmpID`

I have been messing around with the stored procedure, but did not get the result as I wanted. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Also a 200 character employee ID seems quite ambitious. ;)

Comment: You should show us the code and the stored procedure. Also show us the desired result and the result you are actually seeing, otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: That's a whole load of text but you didn't post your stored procedure code. There is also an issue with your data model. You store password with every transaction. There doesn't appear to be a way to validate that the password is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having worked on a clock in/out system, I can warn you now that it is not as simple as you think. If a user misses a clock in or out, you will have to manually insert a new record and then correct all the punch types after that point in time... get ready to write that stored procedure before you move to production! Also, I am going to ignore the odd format of the `EmployeeClock` table - why are you storing the password in it? Regardless, your question is about a stored procedure so let's deal with that.

I assume that there is an `Employee` table that stores the name and the password. The password should be validated before any record is created in the `EmployeeClock` so I will do that. Next, you should see if there is an existing record in `EmployeeClock` for the employee - it could be the first time they ever log in. Finally, if there is an existing record in `EmployeeClock`, create a new record and flip the bit for the `punchType`. Finally, you may want to return a result so you know whether it was successful or not. Additionally, you may want to log the information from a bad attempt somewhere (which I will not show). Putting this all together:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.EmployeeClockInOut
    @EmpID NVARCHAR(200), 
    @Password NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- you should make sure that the employee password is 
    -- correct before you do anything... assume you have a 
    -- Employee table that you can look up
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Employee WHERE EmpId = @EmpID AND [Password] = @Password)
    BEGIN
        -- have they ever clocked in?
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.EmployeeClock WHERE EmpID = @EmpID)
        BEGIN
            -- they have clocked in at least once - flip the punch type
            -- from their last clock in
            INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeClock(EmpID, EmpName, [Password], punchTime, punchType)
            SELECT TOP(1) @EmpID, e.EmpName, @Password, GETDATE(), 
            CASE WHEN c.punchType = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            FROM dbo.Employee AS e 
            INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeClock AS c ON e.EmpID = c.EmpID 
            WHERE e.EmpID = @EmpID 
            ORDER BY c.punchTime DESC;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- there is no clock in record - create first clock in entry
            INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeClock(EmpID, EmpName, [Password], punchTime, punchType)
            SELECT @EmpID, EmpName, @Password, GETDATE(), 1 FROM dbo.Employee WHERE EmpID = @EmpID 
        END

        SELECT 'Clock in/out successful' AS [Result];
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- log the attempt or alert the user...
        SELECT 'EmpID or Password was invalid' AS [Result];
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I did not mean to put the password there. I mean that the application will verify the password whenever the employee clock in/out. Not storing password in the EmployeeClock table. Could you give me some sources to learn how to log the information from a bad attempt?

Comment: @BDragon to log the bad attempt, you would likely just create a new table for LoginAttempt and just INSERT a record in that case.